# Grid breakpoints for columns and grid rows for medium size not working

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, grid, vuetify.js

I am creating grid from scratch in vuejs and have created own component for it,
In my gridCol.vue component I have several props which is passed in App.vue
I need some breaking point for it so in different screen size it can show the different columns as we have in vuetify or in other grid system.
secondly I want to have md=8 and md=4 cols but its not working for me. I have tried looking through the google and have tried several thing but still no luck.
Will be grateful for any help I can get from you.

My gridCol.vue component:

```
<template>
  <div class="col-container">
    <slot>
      <div class="col">{{ cols }}</div> 
    </slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "GridCol",
  components: {},

  props: {
    cols: {
      type: [String, Number, Boolean],
      default: 12,
    },
    xs: {
      type: [String, Number],
      default: 12,
    },
    sm: {
      type: [String, Number],
      default: 12,
    },
    md: {
      type: [String, Number],
      default: 6,
    },
    lg: {
      type: [String, Number],
      default: 1,
    },
    xl: {
      type: [String, Number],
      default: 1,
    },
    align: {
      type: String,
      default: undefined,
    },
  },
  // use computed for breaking points 
  computed: {  
    convertStringToNumber() {
      return this.cols ? parseInt(this.cols) : this.cols;
    },
  },

  methods: {},
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.dl-col-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  /* flex: 1; */
}
</style>
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app" data-app>
    <GridContainer>
      <GridRow>
        <GridCol v-for="col in 1" :key="col" class="col-fullwidth" xs="12" sm="12" md="6" 
            lg="1">
          <Button class="grid-button" variant="primary" label="I used full-width ( 12 
           columns)">
         </Button>
        </GridCol>
      </GridRow>

      <GridRow>
        <GridCol v-for="col in 2" :key="`6${col}`" class="dl-col-fullwidth" xs="12" sm="12" 
             md="6">
          <Button class="grid-button" variant="primary" label="6"></Button>
        </GridCol>
      </GridRow>

       // want to have 8 and 4 cols here 
      <GridRow>
        <GridCol v-for="col in 2" :key="`4${col}`" class="dl-col-fullwidth" xs="12" sm="12" 
            md="4">
          <Button class="grid-button" variant="primary" label="4"></Button>
        </GridCol>
      </GridRow>

      <GridRow>
        <GridCol v-for="col in 3" :key="`4${col}`" class="dl-col-fullwidth" xs="4" sm="4">
          <Button class="grid-button" variant="primary" label="4"></Button>
        </GridCol>
      </GridRow>

      <GridRow>
        <GridCol v-for="col in 6" :key="`2${col}`" xs="2" sm="2">
          <Button class="grid-button" variant="primary" label="2"></Button>
        </GridCol>
      </GridRow>

      <DlGridRow>
        <DLGridCol v-for="col in 12" :key="`1${col}`" xs="1" sm="1">
          <Button class="grid-button" variant="primary" label="1"></Button>
        </GridCol>
      </GridRow>

    </GridContainer>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// all my import goes here, have just removed as I did not want to show.


export default {
  components: {
    GridContainer,
    GridRow,
    GridCol,
    Button,
  },

  data() {
    return {
      // cols: 12,
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.col-fullwidth {
  justify-content: center;
  /* padding: 12px; */
}

.grid-button {
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

For now its looks like below:

[image]

but I want like this:
[image]

How can I fix my breakpoint for different screen sizes:
right know it look like this :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to build a 12-col grid, the number of columns inside a row must always be equal to 12.

Assume that you want to have 4 columns for desktop view (lg), 2 columns for tablet view (md), and 1 column for mobile view (sm), you have to define 3 breakpoint classes for each column. The code will look like the below.

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12">Col</div>
 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12">Col</div>
 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12">Col</div>
 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12">Col</div>
</div>
```

**In Desktop:**
[image]

**In Tab:**
[image]

**In Mobile:**
[image]

**Note:** Don't forget to define media queries for each breakpoint. The CSS properties must be applied only if the media specifications satisfy the breakpoint specifications.

Instead of flex, You can create a grid using [grid CSS properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) that works out of the box. Flex is designed for 1-dimensional system whereas Grid is designed for 2-dimensional system.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, so I have to create media query with Css in my App.vue file, and have to have breaking point for each like for desktop, tab and mobile, Correct ?

Comment: You are right. The classes belong to the specific break point must be enclosed within the media query.

Comment: As you know that I am creating Grid component from scratch and not using any veutify or bootstrap grid so I am not passing any props from them instead passing my own props which I have declare in my gridCol.vue component. I understand the grid concept but its making me confuse too. Tried this but nothing seems to work when resizing
/* mobile phone xs */
``` @media (min-width: 360px) {
  .dl-col-fullwidth {
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
}
/* tablet */
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .dl-col-fullwidth {
    flex-grow: 2;
  }
}  
```
will be helpful for your guide.

Comment: You can refer to this beautiful library https://github.com/kristoferjoseph/flexboxgrid/blob/master/src/css/flexboxgrid.css. This would be helpful!